# Why is Vtable linking issue while adding Javascript window object?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

I am trying to build an application on QT. Here is the application.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QWebFrame>
#include <QWebPage>
#include <QWebView>

class MyJavaScriptOperations : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void sumOfNumbers(int a, int b) {
        qDebug() << a + b;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWebView *view = new QWebView();
    view->resize(400, 500);
    view->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("myoperations", new MyJavaScriptOperations);
    //view->load(QUrl("file:///path/to/my/index.html"));
    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I have the following pro file.

```
QT       += core gui
QT       +=  widgets
QT       += webkit

TARGET = JS_DEMO1
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

I get the following error while building.

(.text.startup+0x8c):-1: error: undefined reference to `vtable for MyJavaScriptOperations'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Q_OBJECT` macro is used outside header file, you need to add `#include "<BASENAME>.moc"`. This will tell `qmake` to run `moc` on the file to generate code for QObject (signals/slots etc.).

So in your case just put `#include "main.moc"` at the end of `main.cpp` file and rebuild the project.

Comment: #include "main.moc" not such file or directory?

Answer (score 2):

So, possible reasons for `error: undefined reference to vtable` and the corresponding solutions are:

- A class has inherited pure virtual functions and haven't overrided them yet. Override them.
- A class has been declared as `QObject's` heir and with `Q_OBJECT` macro after `moc` have been made. Make `moc` again.
- A header had not been included in `.pro` or had been added to it **after** `Q_OBJECT` appeared in the header. Rebuild the project, or (the short way) update the timestamp of `.pro` and make a Build again. E.g., short way to update timestamps of all projects is  `find . -name '*.pro' -exec touch '{}' \;`

The latter two seem to cause your case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do I make moc again.?

Comment: Important note: there is the fourth option — to rebuild the project from scratch, but I did not mention it for purpose: though this fits for small projects, for large ones it would cost tens of minutes to `make distclean` and build again. This option is overkill.